# Long mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_auction_listing 
  JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_auction_listing.user_id = tbl_user.user_id 
  JOIN tbl_subject ON tbl_auction_listing.subject_id = tbl_subject.subject_id 
  JOIN tbl_medium ON tbl_auction_listing.medium_id = tbl_medium.medium_id 
  JOIN tbl_style ON tbl_auction_listing.style_id = tbl_style.style_id 
 WHERE tbl_auction_listing.item_number = '2736503389’
```

which is causing some issues with the site speed, sometimes to the point the site crashes. Would it be better for me to split this into multiple queries?

Indexes

```
tbl_auction_listing 0   PRIMARY 1   auction_listing_id  A   18739               BTREE       
tbl_auction_listing 1   Listing - subject_id    1   subject_id  A   32          YES BTREE       
tbl_auction_listing 1   Listing - medium_id 1   medium_id   A   32          YES BTREE       
tbl_auction_listing 1   Listing - style_id  1   style_id    A   38          YES BTREE       
tbl_auction_listing 1   Listing - colour_id 1   colour_id   A   30          YES BTREE       
tbl_auction_listing 1   Listing - user_id   1   user_id A   1441                BTREE       
tbl_auction_listing 1   Listing - price_id  1   price_id    A   20          YES BTREE       
tbl_auction_listing 1   Listing - status    1   status  A   8           YES BTREE
```

Comment: What are your indexes and what is the explain plan? Do you really need to select _everything_ from all of those tables?

Comment: Also, what's the long polling part? Are you executing this query in an infinite loop or what? That would surely crash any server indeed.

Comment: Yes I do need to select data from all tables. Not all the information but 3 of the 5 tables have 2 or 3 columns.

Comment: Sorry not polling, just a long query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:
 1. Increase the default http request time out of your web server
 2. Build an index on tbl_auction_listing.item_number
 3. Cache some of those tables which are less prone to change often
 4. Increase the sql query timeout on application and db server
 5. Denormalize the database

Answer (score 0):

No, it would not be better for you to break this query into multiple queries.

It would be better to add indexes into the database to speed the query.  Each of the subtables should have an index on its primary key.  For instance, `tbl_style` should have an index on `tbl_style(style_id)` and so on.

Your indexes are "in the wrong direction".  They should be on the reference tables themselves, not (or not only) on the primary table.